# Enabling compiler warnings in netbeans 8.2 (cygwin, c++)?

Tags: c++, netbeans, ide, cygwin

does someone know how I enable the compile warnings in netbeans 8.2 and cygwin compiler (for c++)?

For example when I write

```
for(int i=0; i<v.size(); ++i) ....
```

I dont get a "signed/unsigned-comparison-warning".

I dont find anything in the settings. The compile-command in the box at the bottem is

```
g++    -c -g -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/main.o.d" -o build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/main.o main.cpp
```

I guess there should be the paramter "-w" for warnings..

can someone help?

Comment: you need to add a `-Wall` to the compile flags

Answer (score 1):

You should go to `File/Project Properties` then select `Build/C++ Compiler`. You can then set the warning levels there. See the screenshot:

[image]

If the *Warning Level* doesn't do it, then just add `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Weffc++` to *Compilation Line/Additional Options* in the same dialog window.

Comment: Thanks this is working. is there an option to set the warning level for all further projects to "more warnings"? Because now I need to go to project properties for every new project, because on default it is set to "some warnings".

Comment: @quadlock I am not sure if you can do this automatically. Perhaps there is a way of creating a project template. I never did this as usually I don't have 100s of projects. BTW, you should also consider [CLion](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/) as an IDE. It's very modern, based on IntelliJ platform and `CMake`, so you can batch-process the projects.